# What's more efficient in Python: `key not in list` or `not key in list`?

Tags: python, sequence, contains, in-operator, not-operator

Just found out that both syntax ways are valid.

Which is more efficient?

```
element not in list
```

Or:

```
not element in list
```

?

Comment: Why only these, ?, maybe like i.e (`a is not None` or `not a is None`) etc..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They behave identically, to the point of producing identical byte code; they're equally efficient. That said, `element not in list` is usually considered preferred. PEP8 doesn't have a specific recommendation on `not ... in` vs. `... not in`, but it does for `not ... is` vs. `... is not`, and [it prefers the latter](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations):

> Use `is not` operator rather than `not ... is`. While both expressions are functionally identical, the former is more readable and preferred.

To show equivalence in performance, a quick byte code inspection:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis('not x in y')
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (x)
              2 LOAD_NAME                1 (y)
              4 COMPARE_OP               7 (not in)
              6 RETURN_VALUE

>>> dis.dis('x not in y')
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (x)
              2 LOAD_NAME                1 (y)
              4 COMPARE_OP               7 (not in)
              6 RETURN_VALUE
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're doing:

```
not x in y
```

And if `x` is in `y`, it will basically simplify to `not True` which is:

```
>>> not True
False
```

**In the other hand**, `x not in y` is just direct checking `not in`

To see the timings (always pretty similar):

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit(lambda: 1 not in [1,2,3])
0.24575254094870047
>>> timeit.timeit(lambda: not 1 in [1,2,3])
0.23894292154022878
>>>
```

Also btw, `not` basically just do the opposite (if something is True, not will make it False, same point with the opposite

See [`not` operator](http://thomas-cokelaer.info/tutorials/python/boolean.html)

Comment: @Downvoter why a downvote

Comment: I didn't downvote, but your own links show that the bytecode is the same, so...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga That's true, sorry for that, 